# Laravel 5 the image was lose after edit

Tags: php

i tried to change the photo with update function. but after i click submit, the photos was lose , anyone can help?

this is controller

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $this -> validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required',
        'image' => 'required',
        'address' => 'required',
        'code' => 'required',
        'region' => 'required',
        'city' => 'required',
        'country' => 'required',
        'number' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required',
        'c_title' => 'required',
        'c_name' => 'required',
        'fax' => 'required'
    ]);


    $id = $request -> name;

    $update = Supplier::findOrFail($request -> id_supplier);
    $data = Supplier::find($request -> id_supplier);
    if($request->hasFile('image'))
    {
        Storage::delete($data->image);
        $image = Storage::putFile('public/',$request->image);
    }

    $update -> update($request-> all());
    $data -> image=$image;

    Session::flash('u_success','Supplier ' . $id . ' Has Been Updated.');

    return back();
}
```

it did't show any error but the image did't show

BEFORE EDITED

[the image showed here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24OME.png)

AFTER

[The Image Was lose](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbCMU.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my below updated code.

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $this -> validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required',
        'image' => 'required',
        'address' => 'required',
        'code' => 'required',
        'region' => 'required',
        'city' => 'required',
        'country' => 'required',
        'number' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required',
        'c_title' => 'required',
        'c_name' => 'required',
        'fax' => 'required'
    ]);


    $id = $request -> name;

    $update = Supplier::findOrFail($request -> id_supplier);

    if($request->hasFile('image'))
    {
        Storage::delete($update->image);
        $image = Storage::putFile('public/',$request->image);
        $update->image = $image;
    }

    $update -> update($request-> all());

    Session::flash('u_success','Supplier ' . $id . ' Has Been Updated.');

    return back();
}
```

Comment: Give me error message. or check whether new image will save or not.

Comment: the error is "Trying to get property 'image' of non-object"